# removeFromSuperview crash random

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, crash, automatic-ref-counting

I don't know how to describe the normal scene, It's cause 0.3% crash when called `removeFromSuperview`.

Here's the trace:

```
Exception Type: SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x43746553
Crashed Thread: 0
0 libobjc.A.dylib 0x000000019340fbd0 objc_msgSend + 16
1 UIKit 0x000000018771f0e8 ___UIViewWillBeRemovedFromSuperview + 404
2 UIKit 0x0000000187452c0c -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 108
...
```

All the code is :

```
[_control removeFromSuperview];
_control = nil;
```

What I'm true is

1.It called in main thread.

2.I debug my app and never meet the crash.

3.The class is ARC.

Hope some news come soon.

---

2016.09.02

I meet it again after I try to protected with these

```
if(_control && _control.superview) {
   [_control removeFromSuperview];
    _control = nil;
}
```

Any suggest is appreciated as I am totally stumped.

Comment: When are you calling `[_control removeFromSuperview]`, the crash suggest the object `_control` might have been released before calling the method.

Comment: I forgot to say , the class is arc. Shall I concern about release in arc ?

Comment: No but it may happen that before calling the method the object `_control` has been released through ARC.

Comment: If things liked you say, should I add line  like `if (_control){}` can help the crash? I have no idea what scene would release my view in ARC...

Comment: Yes that will prevent the crash, but your won't be able to call `removeFromSuperView`, try to find the execution call sequence by adding `NSLogs` that will give you idea.

Comment: I try to debug , but I can't meet it anyway. thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your `control` object belongs to a `UIViewController` so when you call `self.control` or `_control` you actually call `yourViewController.control`.
But if you try to call `self.control` whereas your `UIViewController` is already deallocated ( it doesn't exist anymore ), this will cause a crash.

You could try to call `self.control` with a `weak` reference to your controller :

```
__weak MyObject *weakSelf = self;
[weakSelf.control removeFromSuperview];
weakSelf.control = nil;
```

Calling `weakSelf.control` doesn't hold any reference here which means that when your `UIViewController` is deallocated, your `control` will also be deallocated so this won't cause a crash anymore.

It might not be the actual cause of the problem but it's a possibility.

Comment: if you set an object with weak reference. it will not retain longer.it will be deallocated.so that the app will crash